# trying to fix a button/ view controller in java

Tags: java, android, viewcontroller

I'm having issues with my view controller in my android application. I'll admit I'm a noob at android programing please forgive me here is my issue and photos of the application. Basically i just what to press the button and go to the related page and i can't quite figure it out.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbBM5.jpg

```
package com.Apps.jarredapp;

public class ViewController extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

        Button btnSearchStudent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button btnNewStudent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button btnLegalInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        btnSearchStudent.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnNewStudent.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnLegalInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1: {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchStudentActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.button2: {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewStudentActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.button3: {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, LegalInfoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    {


Button searchStudentButton;
Button newStudentButton;
Button legalButton;

searchStudentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

searchStudentButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, searchStudentActivity.class);
    CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});

newStudentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

newStudentButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, newStudentActivity.class);
    CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});

legalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

legalButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, legalActivity.class);
    CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: Can you be a little more elaborate on what you are expecting?

Comment: I'm getting errors on half the code and nothing will communicate

Comment: is the code you posted exactly how your ViewController class is?

Comment: you should keep the onCreate() and the OnClick() with the switch in it, all the other buttons and onclicklisteners are defined at class level, you cant do that, how they are in the begining is fine, from Button searchStudentButton; down, get rid of that, then try, and make sure you are declaring the activitys in the manifest that are in your cases in the switch

Answer (score 0):

You have written two onclicklisteners for one button, use only one then it will work